# Get Percentile with Quantity in column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, percentile

I wish to get the 25% Percentile. Median and 75% Percentile with below example dataset:

```
Item No.    Quantity     Avg Cost
---------------------------------
ABC001      14           100
ABC001      10            90
ABC001      20           130
ABC001      25           110
ABC001      18            80
ABC002      30          1000
ABC002      40          1200
ABC002      28          1300
ABC002      50           950
```

I wish to get this result:

```
Item No     25% Percentile      Median       75% Percentile
-----------------------------------------------------------
ABC001       90                  110          110
ABC002      950                 1000         1200
```

The result generated base on `Quantity`, but I don't know how to do it with using `PERCENTILE_CONT`, as this function is not supporting the "Quantity" concept.

To avoid confusion, I would further explain on the dataset:
ABC001 = {80,80,80,80....(x18), 90,90,90...(x10), 100...(x14), 110..(x25), 130...(x20)}
ABC002 = {950,950....(x50), 1000,1000,1000...(x30), 1200...(x40), 1300..(x28)}

Would anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `PERCENTILE_CONT`:

```
SELECT
    [Item No],
    MAX(pct25) AS [25% percentile],
    MAX(pct50) AS Median,
    MAX(pct75) AS [75% percentile]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Item No],
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Avg Cost])
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Item No]) pct25,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Avg Cost])
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Item No]) pct50,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Avg Cost])
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Item No]) pct75
   FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY [Item No];
```

### Demo

Note that my output does not agree completely with your expected output.  Maybe you did not show the entire data set.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thank you very much for your reply!! I have tried this solution already but I cannot get my expected result. 

To use above solution, it will ignored the "Quantity" column in my dataset, as for example, ABC001 would have 14 pcs in Avg Cost 100, so the total number of ABC001 should have 87 items which 14 pcs is in Cost 100, 10 pcs in Cost 90, etc. 

So is it possible to use PERCENTILE_CONT to achieve this? 

thanks a lot~!

Comment: Your expected result, based on the exact sample data you gave, is wrong.  Check what the definition of median is.

Comment: yes, i calculated wrong manually, both the median and 75% of Item ABC001 should be 110.

Comment: but from your solution, i got unit cost 100 as Median for item ABC001, since the column "Quantity" of each item is ignored.

Comment: `ABC001` has the values, in order `{80, 90, 100, 110, 130}`.  The middle value is `100`, which is the median.  The 75% value is `110`.  My query reports both of these values correctly.

Comment: actually the dataset of ABC001 is {80,80,80,80....(x18), 90,90,90...(x10), 100...(x14), 110..(x25), 130...(x20)}, this is the data set with using the columns "Quantity"

Comment: Stop changing your question after I already answered it.  If you want another answer, you may wait for someone else to post.

Comment: I didn't change the question, actually i am always asking this from the beginning... I have marked the question title with Quantity. I am looking for solution if Quantity  marked in the dataset but not shown row by row using function PERCENTILE. Sorry to make you confused.